# variables of incompatible width

Tags: c, memory, pointers, int, long-integer

I am using the following code to simplify assigning large values to specific locations in memory:

```
int buffer_address =  virtual_to_physical(malloc(BUFFER_SIZE));
    unsigned long int ring_slot = buffer_address << 32 | BUFFER_SIZE;
```

However, the compiler complains "warning: left shift count >= width of type". But an unsigned long int in C is 64 bits, so bit-shifting an int (32 bits) to the left 32 bits should yield a 64 bit value, and hence the compiler shouldn't complain. But it does.

Is there something obvious I'm missing, or otherwise is there a simple workaround?

Comment: Your question is incomplete, you should mention OS and compiler (maybe even compiler settings) as those do matter on such issue.

Comment: @Till: Technically they do, but for teaching value they don't.

Comment: @nightcracker You are so right, I totally missed the premature pointer shifting and assumed other reasons for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

`buffer_address` is a (32-bit) `int`, so `buffer_size << 32` is shifting it by an amount greater than or equal to its size.

```
unsigned long ring_slot = ((unsigned long) buffer_address << 32) | BUFFER_SIZE:
```

Note that 'unsigned long' need not be 64-bits (it is not on Windows - 32-bit (ILP32) or 64-bit (LLP64); nor it is on a 32-bit Unix machine (ILP32)).  To get a guaranteed (at least) 64-bit integer, you need `unsigned long long`.

There are few machines where `int` is a 64-bit quantity (ILP64); the DEC Alpha was one such, and I believe some Cray machines also used that (and the Cray's also used 'big' `char` types - more than 8 bits per `char`).

Answer (score 2):

An `unsigned long int` is not necessarily 64 bits, but for the simplicity let's assume it is.

`buffer_address` is of type `int`. Any expression without any "higher" types on `buffer_address` should return int. Thereby `buffer_address << 32` should return int, and not `unsigned long`. Thus the compiler complains.

This should solve your issue though:

```
unsigned long ring_slot = ((unsigned long) buffer_address) << 32 | BUFFER_SIZE;
```

---

Please note, an `unsigned long` is **not** necessarily 64 bits, this depends on the implementation. Use this instead:

```
#include <stdint.h> // introduced in C99

uint64_t ring_slot = ((uint64_t) buffer_address) << 32 | BUFFER_SIZE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of the expression on the right side of the `=` sign does not depend on what it's assigned to.  You must cast to unsigned long first.

```
unsigned long int ring_slot = (unsigned long)buffer_address << 32 | BUFFER_SIZE;
```